# PHP, OOP practical example

Tags: php, oop, interface, abstract

i am learning about the difference between abstract classes and interfaces,
but theoretical explanations are hard to understand when you don't have practical example.
i have read that:
By updating the base class, all inheriting classes are automatically updated with the change. Interfaces, on the other hand, cannot be changed once created. If a new version of an interface is required, you must create a whole new interface.
if can someone please supply me an practical example for this lines i will be very thankful,
Wishing you a pleasant week.

Comment: This question has been asked and discussed many times (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Class+vs.+Interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example. We have a drivable interface, automobile abstract, and a Pinto class that uses both.

```
interface Drivable 
{
  public function go();
}

abstract class Automobile 
{
  public $type;

  public function getType() {
    return $this->type;
  }
}

class Pinto
    extends Automobile
    implements Drivable 
{
  public function go() {
    // code to make it go
  }
}
```

We can easily add methods to all automobiles by defining them in `Automobile`. Any new method added there will be available to all extending classes.

However, if we add a method to the Drivable interface, we must seek out and implement said method in every class that implements it to add the new method or else it won't compile.

For example, say we add a `stop()` method to our interface. `Pinto` will immediately raise errors because it doesn't have a `stop` method.

Comment: thank you very much, that was really good explanation i undertand now thank you everyone, Wishing you a pleasant week.

Comment: @mike this is great. This solved a mind blowing confusion on my head. Nice example too

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces can be changed, you just need to implement all the changes in the inheriting classes. For example, you are making a SpaceShip interface and you have CoolEnemyShip, StupidEnemyShip, PlayerShip and you have added a new function to SpaceShip to add something new, like Boost() function, you have to implement the Boost() function in the 3 implementation classes(CoolEnemyShip, StupidEnemyShip, PlayerShip)

On the other hand, if SpaceShip was a base class, and you implemented Boost() function in that, all the inheriting classes will have the Boost() function avaialble. THat is the main difference, you should not need a line of code to understand it, just analogies should help you enough.

Comment: First Thank You, Your explanation is presented for an excellent and I would imagine that the explanation was really great but I do not understand the difference between interface and abstract classes, If you can please write code coordinated with your explanation i think it will help me understand, and again thank you.

Comment: abstract class: can have implemented methods. interface: just what methods are to be implemented

Answer (score 1):

Abstract base classes are for creating functionality that extending classes will inherit.

Interfaces are for defining a strict set of functions that must be implemented by the classes that use this interface.

There is a little bit of overlap in that abstract classes can mark a method as abstract leaving the implementation up to the inheriting classes.

Comment: so if i understand by your explanation, when we using abstract class the class that inherit our abstract class is overrides our Bodiless abstract class method's or It continues them And ignores the name of the method